# Error Occurred,(Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS)

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
UPDATE tblEmployee SET EPFNo=RIGHT('0000'+CAST(EpfNo AS VARCHAR(4)),4)
WHERE EPFNo IN (SELECT EPFNo,LEN(EpfNo) FROM tblEmployee
GROUP BY tblEmployee.EPFNo
HAVING LEN(EpfNo) = 4)
```

Comment: Why is there a subquery? It looks like you are padding EPFNo when it is a certain length. Can't you use the much simpler `UPDATE tblEmployee SET EPFNo = RIGHT('0000'+CAST(EpfNo AS VARCHAR(4)),4) WHERE LEN(EPFNo) = 4`?

Comment: Noted.., Thanks Paresh J &  Andy Nichols

Answer (score 0):

Remove `LEN(EpfNo)` from subquery:

```
UPDATE tblEmployee SET EPFNo=RIGHT('0000'+CAST(EpfNo AS VARCHAR(4)),4)
WHERE EPFNo IN (SELECT EPFNo FROM tblEmployee
GROUP BY tblEmployee.EPFNo
HAVING LEN(EpfNo) = 4)
```

You cannot specify more than 1 column in such cases (as error says)

Answer (score 0):

Your specific problem is the `len()` in the `select`.  However, I don't think the logic makes sense.

First, you don't need an aggregation in the subquery:

```
UPDATE tblEmployee
    SET EPFNo = RIGHT('0000' + CAST(EpfNo AS VARCHAR(4)), 4)
    WHERE EPFNo IN (SELECT e2.EPFNo
                    FROM tblEmployee e2
                    WHERE LEN(e2.EpfNo) = 4
                   );
```

Having written that, I notice that you are comparing `EPFNo` . . . the length is the same with or without the subquery.  So, this should be the same:

```
UPDATE tblEmployee
    SET EPFNo = RIGHT('0000' + CAST(EpfNo AS VARCHAR(4)), 4)
    WHERE LEN(EpfNo) = 4;
```

Then you are right padding this.  But the length is already 4.

For some reason, I suspect that you want something like this:

```
UPDATE tblEmployee
    SET EPFNo = RIGHT('0000' + LTRIM(RTRIM(EpfNo)), 4)
    WHERE LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(EpfNo))) <> 4;
```